# Updating Time Zone for a Date field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that has date field in UTC default format. I want to also store the same date/time in PST format in another column in same table. Is it possible to do it in an SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `convert_tz` to do conversion between different time zone.

```
mysql> select convert_tz('2016-03-16 7:00:00', '+00:00','-08:00');
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| convert_tz('2016-03-16 7:00:00', '+00:00','-08:00') |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 2016-03-15 23:00:00                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

To do the task you mentioned in your post, just use a `UPDATE` as below

```
update tbl set col2 = convert_tz(col1, '+00:00','-08:00');
```

Comment: Actually I dont want to save it at table level. So let's say if there is a utc date field like "2016-03-16 7:00:00", then I want to update the value in pst date field to "2016-03-15 23:00:00". Is there a Date function that can be applied to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I figured it out. Using DATE_SUB(datetimeutc,INTERVAL 8 HOUR) resolved my problem.